# Gitlab: Can I create a Branch visible to only certain developers?

Tags: permissions, authorization, branch, gitlab

Im using gitlab, and I am wondering, is there a simple way to restrict access to a branch to only certain developers?  This has to do with time varying disclosure and the ability for certain developers to see some objects models, while other cannot?  Ideally this would happen in one repository, without a proliferation of forks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have a read protection to certain git branches. That would also defeat how git works.

What you could do is forking a repository, creating a branch here and only grant restricted permission to the entire repository. Later it would always be possible to merge changes from this forked repository to the original repository.

You can only change read access to the entire repository as well as write permission to branches.